# Excel - Substitute for indirect within sumif for dynamic column name

Tags: excel, dynamic, excel-formula, sumifs

I am trying to find a substitute for a dynamic column name within my sumif formula so I don't use the volatile indirect command. How can I make a reference in a more optimal way so my file isn't so slow due to indirect?  In other words, what can I switch out for the indirect($F$9) part

The column name changes from Budget_1, Actual_1, Prior_1 for example and they are all column names in another sheet. I am stuck...thanks in advance

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT($F$9),
Main_Co_Dept,CONCATENATE($B14,RIGHT($D$1,4),RIGHT($I$1,4)),
EBITDA_Co,CONCATENATE("0000-",RIGHT($D$1,3)))
```

Comment: dont let me down boys

Comment: I don't know if it also applies to SUMIFs but apparently there are instances where SUMIF can be volatile https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/451367-indirect-non-volatile.html